# Netlogo : Optimize calculation of turtle neighbor within a patch

Tags: performance, optimization, netlogo

I need to calculate nearest neighbor turtle in the same patch for all the turtles constrained by some properties. The code which I have written takes a lot of time and am wondering if there is any other way to optimize it. I have defined a property *neighbor* in turtle to store the nearest neighbor.

```
to set_neighbor  
  ask patches [
    ask turtles-here with [ life_stage = "STAGE1" ] [
      set neighbor min-one-of other turtles-here with [ life_stage != "STAGE2" ] [ (distance myself) ]
    ]
  ]  
end
```

I tried to optimize the code by making the following changes but it ended up taking more time. I assumed if I stored the results of a query in a variable and used the variable later multiple times it would be quicker than executing the query itself multiple times.

```
to set_neighbor  
  ask patches [
    let turt_temp turtles-here with [ life_stage != "STAGE2" ]
    ask turtles-here with [ life_stage = "STAGE1" ] [
      set neighbor min-one-of other turt_temp [ (distance myself) ]
    ]
  ]  
end
```

I would really appreciate any pointers for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why have the patches ask the turtles at all? This should do exactly the same thing, but a good bit faster, especially if you have a lot of patches with no turtles at `STAGE1`:

```
to set_neighbor  
  ask turtles with [ life_stage = "STAGE1" ] [
    set neighbor min-one-of other turtles-here with [ life_stage != "STAGE2" ] [ (distance myself) ]
  ]
end
```

I'm not sure just looking why your second implementation was slower. I could see it being slower if you have a lot of patches without any turtles at `STAGE1` (especially if there a lot of other turtles on them).

Comment: Is `other` necessary for the real model. In this example, only asking stage1 turtles and only choosing from stage2 turtles.

Comment: The `STAGE2` check is an inequality, not an equality, so it includes `STAGE1` turtles. Thus, `other` is necessary. It's good to think about though, since removing an unnecessary `other` would speed things up!

Comment: good point - i didn't read it carefully enough. better go fix my answer too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I tried out your suggestion but this is also taking more time than the original code.
The idea behind asking the patches was to somehow cache turtles-here and calculate all the neighbors for turtles within a patch at a time.

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind including a picture of the typical state of your model in your question? The performance here is going to depend a lot on how agents are distributed.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Some features of the model - turtles do not move, and the maximum number of turtles per patch is close to 100. I am not sure if this is what you were asking for. Can you please clarify what do you mean by a picture of the typical state of the model ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option (and I can't tell which would be faster) is to restrict the number of asks by only doing it where there are both stage1 and not(stage2) turtles on the same patch. I have also used `with-min` instead of `min-one-of` but again I don't know which is quicker.

```
to set_neighbor
  ask patches with [ any? turtles with [ life_stage = "STAGE1" ] and any? turtles with [ life_stage != "STAGE2" ] ]
  [ ask turtles-here with [ life_stage = "STAGE1" ]
    [ set neighbor other turtles-here with [ life_stage != "STAGE2" ] with-min [ distance myself ]
    ]
  ]
end
```